# How to pass values from level 3 to 1 in view heirarchy via using Delegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, delegates, message-passing

I have 3 classes lets say A,B and C, and A pushes B and B pushes C now I want to quick jump back from C to A but I want to get some values.
I know this is possible via Notifications but Is this possible via using Delegate.
I also declare class C into A like following.

//in class A

```
C *c = [C new];
c.delegate = self;
```

I done same but delegate method isn't calling in Class A. Need suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `DataModel` class for the values you need to pass.

Create its instance, say `modelObjectInstance` in A.

When pushing B, pass its reference to B.

B performs whatever updates it wants on the `modelObjectInstance`.

When pushing C, pass its reference to C.

C performs whatever updates it wants on the `modelObjectInstance`.

Now when B and C are popped, A has a reference of the `modelObjectInstance` with updated values.

Note: create weak references in B and C for the `modelObjectInstance`, else you will have a retain cycle.

Comment: Will that work on directly jumping back C to A, because Its my requirement to move A->B->C then moving back C->A?

Comment: Yes. The ownership of the object remains with A and you would be just passing a reference to B and C. Essentially, they are modifying values inside the same object. Just be careful that at no point you directly set the value of the object to another reference. Just update the values in the same refenece eg. modelObject.value1 = whateverValue.

Comment: I've performed same flow with nsstring but its not working in A string is create with Strong reference and in B and C with Weak. where I am wrong?

Comment: Another reason that comes to mind why this might not be working for you is that you have directly used a string. That would not work. NSString by default is of 'copy' type. So using NSString will not work. Create a Custom class with a property of type NSString. Then pass this object around. Also do not forget to initialise this object when you create it in 'A'.